# Belkin won't upload to my desktop PC

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I had to reinstall windows and all programs to my Gateway desktop. I have Windows XP and use IE. I can't get the Belkin wireless program to upload. It says it is, but will not produce a link in my Internet connections. It will not allow my to sign in or complete process of adding this program to my computer. It worked just fine before I reinstalled Windows and factory settings. What could be stopping it??

Comment: Is this built in wireless? Some sort of PCI card?

Comment: It's a belkin wireless router. It's attached to a desktop downstairs and I had the software added to my desktop pc upstairs and it worked, but since the reinstall...it refuses to upload

Comment: @Trin: you should read your own question and try to reword it, adding error-messages might help, too.

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry, I was at work haha!

Answer (score 2):

No router requires software on a connected computer in order to function.  Any software that accompanies a router is only there to make changing the router settings easier.

You are using XP.  So... click the Start button, click Run, type CMD in the box and hit ENTER.  Then, from the little DOS window that opens, type IPCONFIG and hit enter.  You will see some information... the last piece should be DEFAULT GATEWAY.  This has nothing to do with the fact that you have a Gateway computer.  See those numbers after DEFAULT GATEWAY?  Probably 192.168.2.1 or something similar?  That is the IP address of your router.  If you open up IE and you type in the address bar...

http:// -default gateway-

... and by -default gateway- I mean those numbers you saw listed for your default gateway.  So, you would type something like this...

http://192.168.2.1

... and hit enter.  This would bring you to the Belkin Wireless Router Setup Utility.

Now... part of the problem here with your question, is your usage of the word UPLOAD.  I don't think it means what you think it means.  UPLOAD means to send information away from your computer, up to a server or the internet in general.  DOWNLOAD means to receive information to your computer, from a server or the internet in general.  So, from what you are saying, you can connect to the internet just fine with the router, and you can download information off the internet just fine, but whenever you attempt to UPLOAD anything (sending an email, making a post here, asking questions, chatting, etc) it fails.  So, we need to determine what you **ACTUALLY** mean when you say Upload.

What I *think* you mean, is that whenever you put in the CD that came with the router, the software fails to install properly.  You are still getting online and you can upload and download just fine... but your router is not listed as an Internet Gateway in "Network Connections" like it was before you reinstalled Windows.

The problem *could* be that you have not updated Windows completely since you reinstalled it.  But honestly, since I have already shown you how to log into your router without the special Belkin software, AND it functions just fine without the software, there is no need to even bother with it any more.